# AWS Stack Updates and ENIs

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

When I try to update a stack with a new image for one of the instances, I get an error saying: "Interface: yyy in use". It sounds like because I'm using ENIs in my stack template, the instance that they are attached to cannot be updated because of them, and the stack doesn't seem smart enough out-of-box to detach and reattach the ENIs as needed for the update.

How would I go about solving this?

EDIT:
Here's the configuration of the instance and the ENI in the stack template.

```
"DomainControllerIP": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",
    "Properties": {
        "Domain": "vpc"
    }
},

"DomainControllerEIPAssociation" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation",
  "Properties" : {
    "AllocationId" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "DomainControllerIP", "AllocationId" ]},
    "NetworkInterfaceId" : { "Ref" : "DomainControllerServerENI" }
  }
},

"DomainControllerServerENI" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface",
    "DependsOn" : "DomainControllerInstance",
    "Properties" : {
        "Description": "Domain Controller Server ENI",
        "SourceDestCheck": "true",
        "GroupSet": [{ "Ref": "DomainControllerSecurityGroup" }, { "Ref": "DomainMemberSecurityGroup" }],
        "SubnetId": { "Ref": "PublicSubnet4" },
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.30.5.45"
    }
},

"DomainControllerENIAttachment" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::NetworkInterfaceAttachment",
        "Properties" : {
            "InstanceId" : {"Ref" : "DomainControllerInstance"},
            "NetworkInterfaceId" : {"Ref" : "DomainControllerServerENI"},
            "DeviceIndex" : "1" 
        }
},

"DomainControllerInstance": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Properties": {
        "ImageId": { "Ref" : "DomainControllerAMIId" },
        "InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior": "stop",
        "InstanceType": { "Ref" : "DomainControllerInstanceType" },
        "KeyName": { "Ref": "DomainControllerKeyName" },
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": { "Fn::Join" : [ " ", [{ "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" }, "Domain Controller"]]}
            }
        ],
        "SecurityGroupIds": [
            {
                "Ref": "DomainControllerSecurityGroup"
            },
            {
                "Ref": "DomainMemberSecurityGroup"
            }
        ],
        "SubnetId": { "Ref": "PublicSubnet4" }
    }
},
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the relevant parts of the CloudFormation script? It could well be faulty logic in CloudFormation that doesn't know it needs to remove the ENI before stopping the instance.

Comment: @Tim OP updated. Do CloudFormation templates even support automatic detachment of ENIs upon instance replacement? I haven't found anything to suggest that. I've seen CloudWatch and Lambda functions being used for something like this, but that's about it. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/attach-second-eni-auto-scaling/

Comment: I really don't know if CloudFormation can do that sorry. Have you posted on the AWS forums? Someone from the product team might comment.